# Can I move a function in C by copying the data a function pointer points to?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I've written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void hello(){
        puts("hey");
}

int main(){

        char* helloCpy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*hello));

        strcpy(helloCpy, (char*)&hello);
        void (*helloCpyPtr)() = (void (*)()) helloCpy;

        hello();
        helloCpyPtr();

        return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to:

1. get a pointer to a function.
2. allocate memory the size of the function.
3. copy the function into that memory.
4. cast the copied memory into a function pointer.
5. invoke the copy of the function.

Everything goes ok until I invoke "helloCpyPtr()". At this point, I get a seg-fault.

It wouldn't surprise me if what I'm trying to do is impossible. If it is impossible, I'd love to know why it's impossible.

If its not impossible, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

<strike>Thank you stack overflow.</strike>

Comment: Is your goal to just get a function pointer or is it actually to move a function?  Getting a function pointer is trivial.  Moving a function isn't really and I'm not really sure why you'd want to.

Comment: It is not possible to apply `sizeof` to function type.

Comment: 1. `sizeof(*fn)` is meaningless. It certainly doesn't represent the number of bytes required to implement the function. 2. Code may not even be in the same memory as data, as can occur in Harvard-architecture machines. 3. Code may not be "relocatable" in the way you suggest, esp. if it makes PC-relative calls to other functions. You'd need to relocate the code yourself. 4. Even if you had gotten all the above right and were on a von Neumann machine, there may be hardware to stop you from executing data as though it were code – Execute permission bits. You need to set them for this to work.

Comment: Addenda: It's not even guaranteed that a function's code is contiguous in memory! A perverse compiler could interleave the code of two functions and add jumps so that they hop over each other.

Comment: try `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(*hello));`

Comment: I was watching a talk on lmdb, and the presenter proposed "you could even copy your function straight into lmdb, and execute them from there".

I wasn't sure what he meant, but this was my best guess. 

I think I'll spend some time reading up on how JIT compilers do dynamic code construction. I assume they have to deal with Execute permission bits/ DEP (Data Execution Prevention) in some way.

Comment: "Everything goes ok"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that `sizeof(*hello)` is NOT size of the entire function, but rather the size of a function pointer (likely 4-bytes).

I know of no way to get the size of an entire function, so what you're proposing would be impossible.

Other complications are that many major modern operating systems will not let a program execute code from what was created as data-memory.   Your `malloc` statement creates a block of ***data*** not ***code***.

Even if you got the instructions in there, you'd likely get a [DEP (Data Execution Prevention)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/data-execution-prevention-frequently-asked-questions) exception when you tried to call it.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your approach (and you're making this harder by not telling which is your target platform). That said, while it is possible to create executable code at runtime, it doesn't necessary mean that a dumb byte copy will always work.

### The Size of a Function

First, `strcpy` is a bad idea. Your function could contain null bytes, and your function is most likely not terminated by a null byte (`ret` is `0xc3` on x86).

Then, one major problem with the "byte size of a function" is its definition. In most cases, functions are self-contained blocks of codes, but there is nothing to prevent a clever compiler from merging identical parts of multiple functions into a distinct location and simply `jmp` there. In this case, the target function would be non-contiguous and the notion of its size would become ambiguous.

As abelenky correctly suspected in his answer, the standard says (C11, 6.5.3.4./1) that "the `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has a function type". As far as I know, this doesn't mean that doing so is UB in the sense that anything could happen, but it does mean that you can't expect it to do what you think it does in all circumstances. GCC and Clang evaluate it to 1 and emit a warning; Visual Studio, IIRC, will return the contiguous byte size of the function.

One way (relying on unspecified behavior) to get the contiguous byte size of a function is to subtract the address of the next function from the address of the function you wish to copy. **If** the compiler/linker didn't rearrange them, you should get what you want. However, this is a rather big "if", especially if you're working on a large system. Additionally, it relies on casting function pointers to integers, which is different and riskier than casting "normal" pointers to integers (for instance, some ABIs, like most PowerPC ABIs, need more than a code pointer to define a function pointer). I wouldn't do that for anything more than experimentation purposes.

```
void test()
{
    // copy me
}

void test_end()
{
}

int main()
{
    size_t testSize = (intptr_t)test_end - (intptr_t)test;
}
```

### Relocatable Code

Not all code can be ran from anywhere in memory. Code that specifies memory addresses relative to the currently-executing code cannot be copied anywhere. x86_64 has an addressing mode called "RIP-relative", in which you take the executed instruction's address and add an offset to it. ARM has an equivalent (but differently-named) mode, and uses it extensively. This can be used to access global variables or global symbols.

Additionally, on most platforms, most calls and jumps to symbols declared within your program use instruction-address-relative addressing. For instance, if `test` called `test_end` in my previous example, you'd have something like `call +3` (assuming that `test_end` was 3 bytes away in memory).

These techniques make it safe to move your program *as a whole* anywhere in memory, but will fail you if you copy only parts of the program. Taking the `call +3` example again, if you copied only `test` and executed it, your program would crash as it tries to use `test_end`, because you didn't copy it.

This means that you have to be extra-careful about what you write in a function that you plan to manually relocate.

### Executable Memory

As abelenky also correctly noted, modern platforms will refuse to execute memory
that was not marked executable. This is a security feature, and a very useful one at that. However, it means that you need to go through specific hoops to allocate executable memory. `malloc` does not allocate executable memory.

On POSIX platforms, you need to use `mmap` with the `PROT_EXEC` protection (and possibly `PROT_WRITE` to write there) to allocate executable memory. On Windows, you need to use `VirtualAlloc`. I don't remember the flags by heart, but the documentation shouldn't be too hard to find.

### The Whole Process

A simpler thing to do could be to hand-craft the function that you need to copy using assembly language, and make sure that it does not use instruction-address-relative addressing. You can then copy *this* function anywhere in memory, and the rest of your procedure is mostly right: once the memory is allocated and the executable code is copied, chances are (depending on your platform; it works on x86, and I believe that it works on ARM too) that you can cast this memory into a function pointer and invoke it. Here's an example.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

/* assembly code to run execve("/bin/sh") on an x86_64 Linux:
    // push '/bin///sh\x00'
    push 0x68
    mov rax, 0x732f2f2f6e69622f
    push rax

    // call execve('rsp', 0, 0)
    mov rdi, rsp
    xor esi, esi
    push 0x3b
    pop rax
    cdq // Set rdx to 0, rax is known to be positive
    syscall
*/
unsigned char executableCode[] = {
    0x6A, 0x68, 0x48, 0xB8, 0x2F, 0x62, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0x73,
    0x50, 0x48, 0x89, 0xE7, 0x31, 0xF6, 0x6A, 0x3B, 0x58, 0x99, 0x0F, 0x05, 
};

int main()
{
    void* memory = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    memcpy(memory, executableCode, sizeof executableCode);
    void (*start_shell)() = (void (*)())memory;
    start_shell();
}
```

<sub>Assembly code taken from [`shellcraft`](http://pwntools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shellcraft.html).</sub>

As you can see, instead of copying an existing function, I used straight-up native code.